# What is the simplest way to plot x^(1/3) on the interval [-3,3]?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

My question is:

What is the simplest way to plot x^(1/3) on the interval [-3,3]?

Comment: @Kuba your plot is better

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the real valued cube root, i.e. `CubeRoot[x]` or `Surd[x, 3]`?

Comment: @Nasser Maybe but I'm an idiot.

Comment: I haven't encountered the Surd command before. Plot[Surd[x,3],{x,-3,3}] gave me what I needed. However, thanks for all the other answers as well.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to plot all three roots of $y^3=x$ with real and imaginary axes, and with the the complex phase and magnitude indicated by the line colour and thickness:

```
With[{p = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@
  Table[With[{r = Root[#1^3 - x &, i]}, {x, Re[r], Im[r]}], {i, 3}], {x, -3, 3}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "Re[x^(1/3)]", "Im[x^(1/3)]"},
  ColorFunction -> (Hue[(Pi + ArcTan[#2, #3])/(2 Pi)] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]},
   p /. Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.2 CubeRoot@p[[1, 1, pts, 1]], rest]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since you have a reputation over 1000, I presume you're familiar with basic plotting and seek stylistic suggestions.  I prefer to plot the real and imaginary parts separately:

```
Plot[{Re[x^(1/3)], Im[x^(1/3)]}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> {"real", "imaginary"}]
```

[image]

You could, of course, also include `Abs[x^(1/3)]`.